# How to search and get values from jsondecode() response stored in a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, json, jsondecoder

I have the following JSON response in https://mysite/info:

```
{
 "wg0": {
   "privateKey": "[hidden]",
   "publicKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "listenPort": 0,
   "peers": {
     "B3GtLuabWguXoG2Tz8KVukPXx3twn7A+X/SVT8=": {
       "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:5377",
       "latestHandshake": "Oct 28, 2020 1:58:32 UTC",
       "transferRx": "2.432 GB",
       "transferTx": "1.098 GB",
       "allowedIps": [
         "10.85.85.2/32"
       ]
     },
     "2Uqo3X2ubogU92LS4mWsZtF04ah3qJ4gt1g0=": {
       "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:5412",
       "latestHandshake": "Oct 28, 2020 1:58:52 UTC",
       "transferRx": "32.239 MB",
       "transferTx": "220.852 MB",
       "allowedIps": [
         "10.85.85.3/32"
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I need to search in PHP the "allowedIps" value into that response and return corresponding "latestHandshake" value.

For example:

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mysite/info');
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$obj2 = json_decode($result2);

$IPtoSearch = "10.85.85.2/32";

//Now How can I search $IPtoSearch into $obj2 and return latestHandshake value?

...
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Make sure you always include a language tag (PHP) on your posts, that will ensure they get seen by the maximum number of other users.

Comment: Make sure you always include a coding attempt and/or proof of research/toil, this will assure volunteers that you are not just "dumping your requirements".  We don't want you to become dependent upon the volunteers here to "do your work for you".  Help Vampirism is a bad thing.  If you know how to access nested arrays, demonstrate that in your snippet.  If you know how to call `in_array()` show that.  @Mag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your returned JSON is not actually valid, as `00000` is not a valid integer. If you can convert the `00000` into `0`, your JSON will successfully decode and you can find the `latestHandshake` value corresponding to your search IP address like this:

```
$obj2 = json_decode($result2, true);
$IPtoSearch = "10.85.85.2/32";

foreach ($obj2['wg0']['peers'] as $peer) {
    if (in_array($IPtoSearch, $peer['allowedIps'])) {
        $latestHandshake = $peer['latestHandshake'];
        break;
    }
}

echo "Last handshake for $IPtoSearch was at $latestHandshake\n";
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Last handshake for 10.85.85.2/32 was at Oct 28, 2020 1:58:32 UTC
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GssGs)